# Grails FilterPane Date Field

Tags: date, grails, grails-plugin

SOLVED i'm using filterPane grails plugin, but i get this problem when i use date field: instead to display the combobox with days i get the html code about the input select.

Comment: http://s5.postimg.org/chruw8gp3/Immagine.jpg

Comment: yes i found a solution. thk

Comment: Very good, care to share?

Comment: Oh yes sorry. In Config.groovy file, I changed this:                    gsp {
  encoding = 'UTF-8'
  htmlcodec = 'none'                                               with this:                                                           grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"